# Is it possible to reduce the order of matrix A, if eig(A) = eig(A.') = [1;0.3;0;0]? If yes, how?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I have a matrix A

```
A = [0.7000    0.7000         0         0;
         0         0    0.4000    0.4000;
    0.3000    0.3000         0         0;
         0         0    0.6000    0.6000;]
```

if I compute the Eigenvalues of this Matrix and it's transpose I'll get:

```
Eig = [1.0000;
       0.3000;
       0.0000;
       0.0000]
```

From what I am remembering I should be able to reduce Matrix A to a 2x2 Matrix by somehow transforming it to 2 Dimensional Space.
I was thinking of image(A) since there is a 2D kernel mapping to 0. 
However I don't quite get what I am looking for.
In my opinion the result should look like:

```
A_reduced = [0.7 0.4; 
             0.3 0.6];
```

Is there a mathematical approach that justifies this result?
If there is a way, how would I compute it exactly?

Comment: Just because it corresponds to a 2D space doesn't mean that this 2D space is $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is just a 2D subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$. If you want to identify that 2D subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$, then you have to make some arbitrary choice of vector space isomorphism.

Comment: Is it not possible to convert the 2D space that is span in the R4 to a 2D space in R2 with some linear basis transformation?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are looking for , you could write $A = \begin{bmatrix}0.7 & 0 \\
0 & 0.4 \\
0.3 & 0 \\
0 & 0.6 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Generally the SVD is a first port of call for order reduction.